# How to Use an Exclusion Join to Remove Rows In the Right-side Table?

Tags: mysql, left-join, outer-join

In MySQL, I am struggling to create a LEFT OUTER JOIN properly to include all rows from the left-side table which are NOT represented in the right-side table (i.e., if a row exists on the right-side table, then exclude it from the result set).

Following is a simple example with two tables: Food (bread, strawberries, carrots) and Allergies (strawberries)

The goal is to show all Food for which no Allergy exists (i.e., the correct result set is a single row for **Strawberries**)

```
CREATE TABLE TempFood (ProductName VARCHAR(64));
CREATE TABLE TempAllergies (ProductName VARCHAR(64));
INSERT INTO TempFood (ProductName) VALUES ('Bread'), ('Strawberries'),  ('Carrots');
INSERT INTO TempAllergies (ProductName) VALUES ('Strawberries');

SELECT * FROM TempFood 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TempAllergies ON TempFood.ProductName = TempAllergies.ProductName
```

I know I'm making a simple mistake and would appreciate guidance on how to fix my JOIN.

Comment: Try adding `WHERE TempAllergies.ProductName IS NULL` add the end. Might get you a step further.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: "rows from the left-side table which are NOT represented in the right-side table" That is a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for you desired output is a RIGHT OUTER JOIN.

`RIGHT OUTER JOIN TempAllergies ON TempFood.ProductName = TempAllergies.ProductName`

If you want a table with all foods that have no allergies, the answer is -
`SELECT * FROM TempFood LEFT JOIN TempAllergies ON TempFood.ProductName = TempAllergies.ProductName  WHERE TempAllergies.ProductName IS Null`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it. The RIGHT OUTER JOIN syntax actually provides the OPPOSITE of the desired outcome (by showing only the allergies), where as the second statement with LEFT JOIN is perfect. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, the first statement was written for '(i.e., the correct result set is a single row for Strawberries)'.